# Why spider's result is different in cmd.exe and in file?

Tags: python, cmd, scrapy

I write a spider to get someting in a website.I print it in cmd.exe,and I also print it in file,but there are `,`between words in file, there are no `,` in cmd.exe.Here is my code:

```
answer_name = soup.select('.UserLink-link')[1].get_text()
print answer_name
```

the result in cmd.exe is that: `vczh`

the result in file is that: `v,c,z,h`

why?And how can I get the result that no `,`

Comment: post the write to file code, and 知乎来的大兄弟啊.................

Comment: 额额，写入文件我是直接在命令行输入“scrapy crawl  zhihu  -o  bcd.csv”

Comment: post the `yield item` code, I think you yield data in wrong way.

Comment: my code is that:'code'  item['answer_name'] =[n.encode('utf-8') for n in answer_name] . Yes , it's wrong,I have known,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `yield item` code, I think you yield data in the wrong way.